# Consecutive API Calls and Bad Request Messages

Tags: python, api, python-requests, bad-request

I wanted to make API calls for each element in 'title'.

'title' looks like this and is VERY large:

> ABMC-2017-0002
>
> ACF-2015-0001
>
> ACUS-2017-0004
>
> ADF-2017-0005
>
> AMS-DA-14-0095
>
> VA-2017-VHA-0026
>
> VETS-2017-0001

I wanted to go over them like so:

```
try:
    for i in title:
        docketID=i

        url=APIUrl+'docket.json?api_key='+APIkey+'&docketId='+docketID
        response = json.load(urlopen(url).read())
        print('json loaded from URL \n')
        time.sleep(3)

except:
    print json.loads(urlopen(url)).get('errors')[0]
```

'time.sleep(3)' was added later after I kept getting HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. The API calls per hour was limited. But afterwards I'm still getting HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out. 
Does anyone know how I can loop through a list and make consecutive API calls?

Comment: You might not want to list your API key in a public forum.  The 504 might be because you have been blacklisted for x minutes or hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried you code with different `title` and it works

I found title `'EPA-HQ-OAR-2013-0602'` in example on page

https://regulationsgov.github.io/developers/basics/

So your problem seems wrong titles. Or maybe you used `for` loop in wrong way. You should display url to see it and test in web browser.

BTW: if you use `except Exception, ex: print 'error:', ex` then you will know that you have other problem with `.read()`

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json
import time

all_titles = [
    'EPA-HQ-OAR-2013-0602'
]

api_key  = 'PB36zotwgisM02kED1vWwvf7BklqCObDGVoyssVE'
api_base = 'https://api.data.gov/regulations/v3/'

api_url = '{}docket.json?api_key={}&docketId='.format(api_base, api_key)

try:
    for title in all_titles:
        url = api_url + title
        print 'url:', url

        response = urlopen(url) #.read() # <--- Exception
        data = json.load(response)

        print '--- data ---'
        print data
        print '--- keys ---'
        for key in data.keys():
            print 'key:', key

except Exception, ex:
    print 'error:', ex
    print json.loads(urlopen(url)).get('errors')[0]
```

Result:

```
url: https://api.data.gov/regulations/v3/docket.json?api_key=PB36zotwgisM02kED1vWwvf7BklqCObDGVoyssVE&docketId=EPA-HQ-OAR-2013-0602
--- data ---    
{u'unfundedmandates': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Unfunded Mandates'}, u'energyeffects': {u'value': u'Yes', u'label': u'Energy Effects'}, u'publicationPeriod': {u'value': u'Fall 2015', u'label': u'Publication Period'}, u'timeTables': ...
--- keys ---
key: unfundedmandates
key: energyeffects
key: publicationPeriod
key: timeTables
key: federalismImplications
key: impactsAndEffects
key: rin
key: agendaStageOfRulemaking
key: keywords
key: legalAuthorities
key: publicationperiod
key: relatedDockets
key: energyEffects
key: includedinregulatoryplan
key: title
key: generic
key: internationalImpacts
key: agency
key: smallEntitiesAffected
key: ruleMakingStage
key: priority
key: majorRule
key: agendastageofrulemaking
key: subtype
key: type
key: legalauthorities
key: cfrCitation
key: shorttitle
key: requiresRegulatoryFlexibilityAnalysis
key: internationalimpacts
key: governmentlevelsaffected
key: agencyAcronym
key: requiresregulatoryflexibilityanalysis
key: docketId
key: legaldeadlines
key: unfundedMandates
key: numberOfComments
key: federalismimplications
key: includedInRegulatoryPlan
key: majorrule
key: legalDeadlines
key: smallentitiesaffected
key: governmentLevelsAffected
key: docketAbstract
key: contact
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very kind of you to try and access the API yourself to give out the correct answer. I did go ahead and implement your changes and now the server gives a different answer: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden- Which I think it means the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. It indeed works when there is one request but not for successive ones.....